# Музыка (мультимедия) в qt c++

Tags: c++, qt

У меня есть большой проект на qt, в нём есть музыка которая играет на фоне, с помощью либ QMultimedia и QPlayList, музыка лежит в той же папке где и лежит программа т. е -> ./blytype/music.
Далее я "рилизнул свой проект" на флешку с ддл'ками и т. д + положил туда ту самую Qt5Multimedia.dll, но музыка не проигрывается на другом компе, только на моём
В чём может быть проблема, какой ещё dll нужен?
P.S
Папку plugins я перенёс всю

Comment: А звуковая на другом компе есть? Может быть звук выключен?

Answer (score 1):

./blytype/music попытается рассчитать путь от текущей рабочей директории т.е. откуда запущен процесс, потому у Вас работает, а на флешке нет.

Используйте [QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#applicationDirPath) для вычисления полного пути до диры с файлами

Comment: С одной точки зрения вы правы, но у меня так же есть работа с пользователями через ./blytype/users и всё работает отлично